# Show that following set is countable

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that following set is countable:
>
> The set of all algebraic numbers. A real no. $\alpha$ is said to an algebic no. if it is a root of the polynomial $$a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+a_0=0$$ where $a_n \in \mathbb Z.$

I am new to this field. Please help with more argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**

- $\Bbb{Z}$ is countable.
- The Cartesian product of any two countable sets is countable.
- Try constructing a bijection $f\colon \Bbb Z ^{n+1} \to P_n$, where:
  $$P_n = \{a_n x^n+⋯+a_1 x+a_0  \mid  a_0,a_1,…,a_n \in \Bbb Z\}$$
- The union of a countable family of countable sets is countable.
- Polynomials of degree $n$ have at most $n$ roots.
- For any polynomial $p \in P_n$, let $R_p = \{r \mid p(r)=0 \}$. Then consider the sets:
  $$
  S_n = \bigcup_{p \in P_n} R_p \qquad\text{and}\qquad A = \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty S_n
  $$

Answer (score 2):

There are countable many polynomials. And a polynomial does only have finite many zeroes.
Hence...

Comment: @rbm a polyonimal does only have finite many non zero coefficients, and because of the coefficients are integers. So you can explicit enumerate them, at first count polynomials of degree zero, then one then 2 ...

Answer (score 1):

A common way of proceeding is as follows :

For each polynomial, define the *height* as $$h = n + |a_n| + |a_{n-1}| + \dots + |a_0|.$$

Then argue that there are only finitely many polynomial of each height, $h = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$ and therefore only finitely many roots.  Height then can be used to enumerate the algebraic numbers.

Comment: nb.  Ignore the case h = 0.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: How many (n+1)-tuples satisfy $|a_0|+\ldots+|a_n| = m$ for $m=0,1,2,\ldots$?